# C# Regex few questions about patterns

Tags: regex

Hi  how should i set pattern so it match in situation:

text = "FS 2020/MW/12 HT"

1. start with "FS" and contains "MW"
2. can have anything before and after "MW"
3. end with "HT" and contains "MW"
4. start with "FS" and contains "MW" and end with "HT"

Thanks for help

Comment: Hi romeck! What have you tried before?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `^FS.*MW.*HT$`

Example input & output in Python (I do not know C#)

**Input**

```
items = ["FS 2020/MW/12 HT","FS 2020/MWHT","FS 2020//12 HT","FS 2020/MW/12 H"]
for item in items:
    print(re.findall(r'^FS.*MW.*HT$',item))
```

**Output**

```
['FS 2020/MW/12 HT']
['FS 2020/MWHT']
[]
[]
```

Comment: hi if text is "FSW 2020/MW/12 HT" how should i set pattern so it only find as it start with FS. If i give "^FS." it matched. same for "^FS"